# Calculating the row-means with certain conditions

Tags: r

Let's say I have a matrix like so:

```
df <- matrix(data = c(1,2,9,3,7,NA,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), nrow=4, ncol=3, byrow=T)
```

What I want to calculate, are the row-means of the matrix when the the row isn't allowed to have more than one NA. In this case the end result would be a vector of four components and more specifically `c(4,5,NA,NA)`.

I can make separate vectors that meet the requirements like so:

```
df1 <- df[c(which(rowSums(is.na(df))<=1)),]

df2 <- df[c(which(rowSums(is.na(df))>1)),]

rowMeans(df1, na.rm=T)

rowMeans(df2, na.rm=F)
```

But I can't seem to figure out a good way to have just one vector.

Comment: The first element in the output should be `4`

Comment: @Frank You're right, won't do that again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assign the rows that have more than 1 NAs to NA, and then do the `rowMeans` with `na.rm=TRUE`

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df))>1,] <- NA
rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Or we can do this in one step

```
rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE)*NA^(rowSums(is.na(df))>1)
```

Or another option would be to create an index for getting the `rowMeans`

```
 i1 <- !rowSums(is.na(df))>1
 ifelse(i1, rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE), NA_real_)
```